# Copying over array contents results in segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

I'm currently writing a program that generates icosahedron vertices and subdivides them after following a [tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html#icosphere) on it. The MRE of the code is shown below

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef _countof
#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(_Array) / sizeof(_Array[0]))
#endif // _countof

void icosahedron(int radius, float *vertices);
void subdivide(float *vertices, unsigned int *indices, int subdivision_amount, int radius);
void compute_half_vertex(float v1[3], float v2[3], float new_v[3], int radius);
void add_vertices(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3], float *vertices);
void add_indices(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2, unsigned int i3, unsigned int *indices);

int main(void)
{
    int radius = 5;
    float vertices[60];
    unsigned int indices[60];

    icosahedron(radius, vertices);
    subdivide(vertices, indices, 3, radius);

    for(int i = 0; i < _countof(vertices); i++)
    {
        printf("Vertices: %f\n", vertices[i]);
        printf("Indices: %d\n", indices[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void icosahedron(int radius, float *vertices)
{
    float H_ANGLE = M_PI / 180 * 72;
    float V_ANGLE = atanf(1.0f / 2);

    int i1, i2;
    float z, xy;
    float h_angle_1 = -M_PI / 2 - H_ANGLE / 2;
    float h_angle_2 = -M_PI / 2;

    vertices[0] = 0;
    vertices[1] = 0;
    vertices[2] = radius;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        i1 = i * 3;
        i2 = (i + 5) * 3;

        z = radius * sinf(V_ANGLE);
        xy = radius * cosf(V_ANGLE);

        vertices[i1] = xy * cosf(h_angle_1);
        vertices[i2] = xy * cosf(h_angle_2);
        vertices[i1 + 1] = xy * sinf(h_angle_1);
        vertices[i2 + 1] = xy * sinf(h_angle_2);
        vertices[i1 + 2] = z;
        vertices[i2 + 2] = -z;

        h_angle_1 += H_ANGLE;
        h_angle_2 += H_ANGLE;
    }

    i1 = 11 * 3;
    vertices[i1] = 0;
    vertices[i1 + 1] = 0;
    vertices[i1 + 2] = -radius;
}


void subdivide(float* vertices, unsigned int* indices, int subdivision_amount, int radius)
{
    float* tmp_vertices;
    unsigned int* tmp_indices;
    float new_v1[3], new_v2[3], new_v3[3];
    float *v1, *v2, *v3;
    unsigned int index;

    for (int i = 1; i <= subdivision_amount; ++i)
    {
        tmp_vertices = vertices;
        tmp_indices = indices;
        vertices = 0;
        indices = 0;
        index = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < _countof(tmp_indices); j += 3)
        {
            v1 = &tmp_vertices[(int)tmp_indices[j] * 3];
            v2 = &tmp_vertices[(int)tmp_indices[j + 1] * 3];
            v3 = &tmp_vertices[(int)tmp_indices[j + 2] * 3];

            compute_half_vertex(v1, v2, new_v1, radius);
            compute_half_vertex(v2, v3, new_v2, radius);
            compute_half_vertex(v1, v3, new_v3, radius);

            add_vertices(v1, new_v1, new_v3, vertices);
            add_vertices(new_v1, v2, new_v2, vertices);
            add_vertices(new_v1, new_v2, new_v3, vertices);
            add_vertices(new_v3, new_v2, v3, vertices);

            add_indices(index, index + 1, index + 2, indices);
            add_indices(index + 3, index + 4, index + 5, indices);
            add_indices(index + 6, index + 7, index + 8, indices);
            add_indices(index + 9, index + 10, index + 11, indices);
            index += 12;
        }
    }
}

void compute_half_vertex(float v1[3], float v2[3], float new_v[3], int radius)
{
    new_v[0] = v1[0] + v2[0];
    new_v[1] = v1[1] + v2[1];
    new_v[2] = v1[2] + v2[2];
    float scale = radius / sqrtf((new_v[0] * new_v[0]) + (new_v[1] * new_v[1]) + (new_v[2] * new_v[2]));
    new_v[0] *= scale;
    new_v[1] *= scale;
    new_v[2] *= scale;
}

void add_vertices(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3], float *vertices)
{
    vertices[0] = v1[0];
    vertices[1] = v1[1];
    vertices[2] = v1[2];
    vertices[3] = v2[0];
    vertices[4] = v2[1];
    vertices[5] = v2[2];
    vertices[6] = v3[0];
    vertices[7] = v3[1];
    vertices[8] = v3[2];
}

void add_indices(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2, unsigned int i3, unsigned int *indices)
{
    indices[0] = i1;
    indices[1] = i2;
    indices[2] = i3;
}
```

Specifically, the problem is at this line

```
    tmp_vertices = vertices;
    tmp_indices = indices;
    vertices = 0;
    indices = 0;
```

Running the MRE on [this online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com), it specifically tells me that the signal SIGSEV is being received at that line, which as I understand it, means a seg fault. Here is also what the compiler tells me the variables are set to at this time [the value of the local variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lwot.png). Anyways, a quick break down of the problematic chunk of code, as you may have read in the title, what I was trying to accomplish there was copy over the contents of `vertices` and `indices` into `tmp_vertices` and `tmp_indices`, and then clear the contents of `vertices` and `indices`, and fill the arrays back up later on in the function, with the use of the `add_vertices` and `add_indices` functions, because that's what happened in the original article, and I didn't wanna deviate away from that because I don't have enough expertise to be doing that, this is sort of uncharted territory for me. To prove that this was the problematic section, I made this little example snippet, that if you want to test, you just have to replace the `subdivide` function, and `main` function in the already existing MRE.

```
void subdivide(float* vertices, unsigned int* indices, int subdivision_amount, int radius)
{
    float new_v1[3], new_v2[3], new_v3[3];
    float *v1, *v2, *v3;
    unsigned int index;

    for( int i = 1; i <= subdivision_amount; ++i )
    {
        index = 0;

        for( int j = 0; j < _countof(tmp_indices); j += 3 )
        {
            v1 = & vertices[(int) indices[ j ] * 3 ];
            v2 = & vertices[(int) indices[ j + 1 ] * 3 ];
            v3 = & vertices[(int) indices[ j + 2 ] * 3 ];

            compute_half_vertex( v1, v2, new_v1, radius );
            compute_half_vertex( v2, v3, new_v2, radius );
            compute_half_vertex( v1, v3, new_v3, radius );

            add_vertices( v1,     new_v1, new_v3, vertices );
            add_vertices( new_v1, v2,     new_v2, vertices );
            add_vertices( new_v1, new_v2, new_v3, vertices );
            add_vertices( new_v3, new_v2, v3,     vertices );

            add_indices( index,     index + 1,  index + 2,  indices );
            add_indices( index + 3, index + 4,  index + 5,  indices );
            add_indices( index + 6, index + 7,  index + 8,  indices );
            add_indices( index + 9, index + 10, index + 11, indices );
            index += 12;
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    const int vert_count = 60;
    int radius = 1;
    float vertices[ vert_count ] = { 0 };
    unsigned int indices[ vert_count ] = { 0 };

    icosahedron( radius, vertices );
    subdivide( vertices, indices, 1, radius);
    return 0;
}
```

It's only a little portion of course, but when you replace that `subdivide` function with the original, it compiles with no errors, and the only thing that was changed was skipping the copy and clear section of the original function. The problem with that version though is I never get indices or extra vertices from `compute_half_vertex`, so I can't use this one. Also a quick clarification, I am passing through arrays into these functions, but the reason that I'm representing them as pointers instead, is because from what I learned, [arrays get converted into pointers when they're passed into functions anyway](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers-arrays). When I compile it like that it doesn't seem to cause any problems. Forgive me if I got that mixed up / wrong though because I'm still learning and am currently working on putting my knowledge to the test.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, `subdivide` is expecting 6 parameters but you pass 5 (line 21 of your first snippet)

Comment: As noteed ^^^: https://godbolt.org/z/64bWhTcrP

Comment: You're missing the `radius` argument when you call `subdivide()`.

Comment: `subdivide()` never uses the `vertices_arr` and `indices_arr` arguments, what are they for? The name `XXX_arr` suggests that they should be arrays, but they're declared as integers.

Comment: Please note that both `add_vertices` and `add_indices` aren't *adding* anything, they just overwrite the first elements starting from the passed pointers. This *might* be OK, as long as the passed pointers are updated, but the lines you pointed out show that the code is *zeroing* those pointers, so you are passing NULL pointers to the previous functions.

Comment: Then why aren't you using them? I'd call them `vertices_size` and `indices_size`

Comment: But you still don't use them inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `_countof()` will not work on ***pointers***. The result will size of the pointer itself (usually 4 or 8) divided by the size of the referenced object, not the size of the array it references. C does not keep track of it.
2. Even when you replace it with the correct value your code will invoke undefined behaviour as `tmp_indices[j + 1]` (and similar) will eventually access the array outside the bounds
3. &tmp_vertices[tmp_indices[j] * 3] will reference something which outside the array (another UB).

Add some assertions and change the function:

```
void subdivide(float* vertices, unsigned int* indices, int subdivision_amount, int radius, size_t size)
{
    float* tmp_vertices;
    unsigned int* tmp_indices;
    float new_v1[3], new_v2[3], new_v3[3];
    float *v1, *v2, *v3;
    unsigned int index;

    for (int i = 1; i <= subdivision_amount; ++i)
    {
        tmp_vertices = vertices;
        tmp_indices = indices;
        vertices = 0;
        indices = 0;
        index = 0;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j += 3)
        {
            assert(j + 1 < size);
            assert(tmp_indices[j] * 3 < size);
            /* more asserts */

            v1 = &tmp_vertices[tmp_indices[j] * 3];
            v2 = &tmp_vertices[(int)tmp_indices[j + 1] * 3];
            v3 = &tmp_vertices[(int)tmp_indices[j + 2] * 3];

            /* ..... */

        }
    }
}
```

You have more similar errors. Add asserts and see where you access the array outside its bounds.

I did not analyze if the code does what it is supposed to do, only the sigfault problem. You have many out of bounds accesses and you need to find them all (use assert)